# Oracle get all matched occurrences from one column with REGEXP

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Been using this query but I don't get what I want, anyone can help, please? I want to consolidate all the matched multiple occurrences and display the records in the table.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR,'^C-.+|^WHT.+',1, LEVEL,1,'m') AS CHARGE_NUMBER
FROM
(
  SELECT DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(COL_DATA, 2000,1) AS STR, TRANX_DATE, USER_ID
  FROM  TABLE_1 
)
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(STR,'^C-.+|^WHT.+',1,1,'m'))+1
```

Data in one Column

```
A-DATE|27SEP2021|TRANSACTION_NUMBER|0001|USERID|1000
B-THE|QUICK|BROWN|123467899|OVER|THE|1234567899|DOG
C-50000000001
WHT639281234567
B-THE|123456789|BROWN|FOX|OVER|THE|LAZY|DOG
C-50000000002
WHT639281234568
B-THE|1234567899|BROWN|123457899|OVER|THE|LAZY|DOG
C-50000000003
B-THE|QUICK|BROWN|1234567899|OVER|1234567899|LAZY|DOG
WHT639281234569
B-THE|QUICK|BROWN|FOX|OVER|THE|LAZY|DOG
C-50000000004
WHT639281234570
B-THE|1234567899|BROWN|123467899|OVER|THE|1234567899|DOG
```

DESIRED RESULT:

```
CHARGE_NUMBER                           
50000000001
639281234567   
50000000002
639281234568
50000000003   
639281234569
50000000004
639281234570
```

Comment: Please describe the rules. What should be captured from which records and why provided answer *doesn't work* (so bad phrase that provides exactly no information)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option: select values you need (using regex), then remove superfluous characters (`C-` and `WHT`), *looping* through the string as many times as there are `WHT`s *times* 2 (because you have `C-` and `WHT`s to look for).

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'A-DATE|27SEP2021|TRANSACTION_NUMBER|0001|USERID|1000
  3  B-THE|QUICK|BROWN|FOX|OVER|THE|LAZY|DOG
  4  C-50000000001
  5  WHT639281234567
  6  B-THE|QUICK|BROWN|FOX|OVER|THE|LAZY|DOG
  7  C-50000000002
  8  WHT639281234568
  9  B-THE|QUICK|BROWN|FOX|OVER|THE|LAZY|DOG
 10  C-50000000003
 11  B-THE|QUICK|BROWN|FOX|OVER|THE|LAZY|DOG
 12  WHT639281234569
 13  B-THE|QUICK|BROWN|FOX|OVER|THE|LAZY|DOG
 14  C-50000000004
 15  WHT639281234570
 16  B-THE|QUICK|BROWN|FOX|OVER|THE|LAZY|DOG' from dual
 17  )
 18  select replace(replace(regexp_substr(col, 'C-\d+|WHT\d+', 1, level), 'C-', ''), 'WHT', '') charge_number
 19  from test
 20  connect by level <= regexp_count(col, 'WHT') * 2;

CHARGE_NUMBER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
50000000001
639281234567
50000000002
639281234568
50000000003
639281234569
50000000004
639281234570

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot, thank you for the answer, I tried the query it doesn't work. By the way, sometimes C- is/are not there or WHT is/are not there but sometimes both are present...

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot my bad. Technically it works, however if I'm going to remove one C-50000000002 and C-50000000004 the remaining matches do not display at all.